# sublist for partitioning data set

Tags: java, partitioning, bigdata

I have an list of list whose indices reaches upto 100's of millions.Lets say each od the list inside list is an sentence of a text. I would like to partition this data for processing in different threads. I used `subList` to split 
data and send it in different threads for processing. Is this a standard approach for paritioning data? If not , could you please suggest me some standard approch for it?

Answer (score 2):

This will work as long as you do not ["structurally modify"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) the list or any of these sub-lists. Read-only processing is fine.

There are many other "big data" approaches to handling 100s of millions of records, because there are other problems you might hit:

- If your program fails (e.g. OutOfMemoryError), you probably don't want to have to start over from the beginning.
- You might want to throw >1 machine at the problem, at which point you can't share the data within a single JVM's memory.
- After you've processed each sentence, are you building some intermediate result and then processing that as a step 2? You may need to put together a pipeline of steps where you re-partition the data before each step.
- You might find you have too many sentences to fit them all into memory at once.

A really common tool for this kind of work is [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop). You'd copy the data into [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/), run a map-reduce job (or more than one job) on the data and then copy the data out of HDFS when you're done.

A simpler approach to implement is just to use a database and assign different ranges for the integer `sentence_id` column to different threads and build your output in another table.